# Two columns refer to one id in another table

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to work out the following but I can't get my head around it.

I need to match up the player IDs shown within the scores table to the persons table, and return the relevant person's name.  Below is a condensed version of the tables showing the core parts of what's required.

Details will be returned based on the fixtures ID, so whatever person's ID falls on the same row I need to get their names.

Persons' ID is in the form of home_id_1, away_id_1, home_id_2, and away_id_2.

> Persons Table
>   **id**  **fname**  **lname**
>   1  Fred      Bloggs
>   2  John     Brown
>   3  Kevin    Smith
>   4  James   Kirk
>
> Scores Table
>   **Fixtures_ID  home_id_1  away_id_1  home_id_2  away_id_2**
>                1                  1                2                    3                  4

My current SELECT statement is:

```
SELECT scores.fixture_id, scores.match_date, players.fname, players.lname, 
       scores.home_id_1, scores.away_id_1, scores.home_id_2, scores.away_id_2  
    FROM scores, players  
    WHERE fixture_id = 1
```

Output should be something along the lines of:

> **Match Date**  **Home Player 1**  v  **Away Player 1,**  **Home Player 2**  v  **Away Player 2**
>   10/01/2016    Fred Bloggs          John Brown         Kevin Smith            James Kirk

Hope this makes sense, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: Could you please provide example or result you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like following

```
SELECT scores.fixture_id, 
       scores.match_date, 
       CONCAT(p1.fname, p1.lname), 
       CONCAT(p2.fname, p2.lname),
       CONCAT(p3.fname, p3.lname),
       CONCAT(p4.fname, p4.lname),    
       s.home_id_1, 
       s.away_id_1, 
       s.home_id_2, 
       s.away_id_2
FROM scores s 
    INNER JOIN players p1 ON s.home_id_1 = p1.id
    INNER JOIN players p2 ON s.away_id_1 = p2.id
    INNER JOIN players p3 ON s.home_id_2 = p3.id
    INNER JOIN players p4 ON s.away_id_2 = p4.id
WHERE s.fixture_id = 1
```

Maybe you need to use LEFT JOIN if you expect to have null values

Comment: Thanks very much Stan.  Both answers given were so similar but I've gone with this one.  I had to remove 'scores' from the SELECT statement for it to work (not sure why as I would have thought having 'scores' there makes it more unique).

Comment: Using 's' prefix instead of 'scores' should work since it's defined in FROM statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to the players table four times, once for each column you want to match with it. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  scores.fixture_id, 
  scores.match_date, 
  players1.fname + ' ' + players1.lname,
  players2.fname + ' ' + players2.lname,
  players3.fname + ' ' + players3.lname,
  players4.fname + ' ' + players4.lname,
FROM 
  scores, 
  INNER JOIN players players1 ON scores.home_id_1 = players1.id
  INNER JOIN players players2 ON scores.home_id_2 = players2.id
  INNER JOIN players players3 ON scores.away_id_1 = players3.id
  INNER JOIN players players4 ON scores.away_id_2 = players4.id
WHERE
  scores.fixture_id = 1
```